# Add a resizing UIButton's background with gradient color

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, gradient

With this code I can add background to a UIButton with gradient:

```
public func addBackgroundAndGradient(to: UIView, gradient1: CGColor, gradient2: CGColor, cornerRadius: CGFloat = 5){
    let backgroundImage = UIImageView()
    backgroundImage.frame.size = to.frame.size
    backgroundImage.clipsToBounds = true
    backgroundImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    backgroundImage.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    to.insertSubview(backgroundImage, at: 0)

    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        let gradient1 = UIColor(red: 200/255, green: 100/255, blue: 5/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
        let gradient2 = UIColor(red: 1, green: 128/255, blue: 0, alpha: 1).cgColor
        gradient.colors = [gradient1, gradient2, gradient2, gradient1]

    gradient.locations = [0.0, 0.35, 0.65, 1.0]
    gradient.frame.size = to.frame.size
    backgroundImage.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
    backgroundImage.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
}
```

However when I set a new title for the UIButton, the background will not resize. When making the text longer than initial, the text will go beyond the background.

How can I make a resizing background with gradient for a UIButton?

Answer (score 1):

For doing this, you need to create a custom UIButton subclass, and to set CAGradientLayer as its layer class:

```
class ExpandableGradientButton: UIButton {

override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
    get {
            return CAGradientLayer.self
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you need to change your function to:

```
@IBOutlet weak var expandableGradientButton: ExpandableGradientButton!
...
public func addBackgroundAndGradient(to: UIView, gradient1: CGColor, gradient2: CGColor, cornerRadius: CGFloat = 5){
    let backgroundImage = UIImageView()
    backgroundImage.frame.size = to.frame.size
    backgroundImage.clipsToBounds = true
    backgroundImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    backgroundImage.layer.borderWidth = 0.5

    let gradient1 = UIColor(red: 100/255, green: 140/255, blue: 2/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
    let gradient2 = UIColor(red: 123/255, green: 158/255, blue: 54.0/255.0, alpha: 1).cgColor
    if let butonLayer = to.layer as? CAGradientLayer
    {
        butonLayer.colors = [gradient1, gradient2, gradient2, gradient1]
        butonLayer.locations = [0.0, 0.35, 0.65, 1.0]
        butonLayer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
    }
}
```

In other words, you have to use gradient layer as UIButton's layer, and it will be resized automatically. 
Note: This can be also used for any other UIView subclass, not only for UIButton.